# How can I fix this two dimensional array in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, m, i, j, status, maxr = 0, maxc = 9, temp;
    int k, q, r , state = 0, t = 1;
    int ar[n][m];
    puts("Enter two numbers represents two dimensional array, N * M");
    puts("This program will find the saddle points");
    puts("The numbers in arrays is totally random");
    srand((unsigned int) time(0));  //randomize seed
    while (status = scanf("%d %d", &n, &m) != 2)
    {
        if (status == EOF)
            break;
        else
        {
            puts("You should have entered two integers");
            puts("Try again");
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
            puts("Enter two numbers represents two dimensional array, N * M");
            continue;
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) //establish a random two dimensional array
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ar[i][j] = (rand() % 10);
            printf("%d\n", ar[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", ar[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to create a two dimensional array which contains random numbers. So I use the `rand()` function, and random the seed by using `srand` function.

Now I am sure that I get random number, but it seems that I can not  save these **random numbers into the array**. In order to verify this, I create two loop loop, it turns out the result is different. The array `a[i][j]` should be identical, but actually is different.

So how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show us how is initialized `ar` array?

Comment: Why are you looping column major, by the way?

Comment: `int ar[n][m];` the value of `n` and `m` are *undefined*.

Comment: _Any_ question about _any_ code is completely meaningless unless the variable declarations of the involved variables are shown.

Comment: @WeatherVane I posted all my codes. but does `ar[i][j] = rand() % 10;` means give the value of rand()% 10 to ar[i][j]? how it can be trash?

Comment: @Annndy my deleted comment was based on the wrong assumption that you have the array dimensions transposed.

Comment: @Bob__ it is two dimensional array. i controls rows, and j controls columns..

Comment: Yes, that was clear but not cache friendly. Now, you should move the array declaration after the scanf...

Comment: @Bod_ oh, thanks, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `n` and `m` are not initialized to any known values. You need to declare that array *after* `n` and `m` have been read.

When that bug is fixed, for an array defined as `int ar[n][m];` you must iterate over it like this:

```
for(int x=0; x<n; x++)
  for(int(y=0; y<m; y++)
    ar[x][y] = ....;
```

Not only to prevent the obvious out-of-bound bugs, but also to guarantee best use of data cache. Given array data `ar[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}`, it is stored in memory as

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

This is cache-friendly, since all values are stored adjacently. If you iterate through this memory left to right, the array could be stored in cache memory and the CPU does not need to fetch the values from RAM at every lap in the loop, which is slower.

Comment: n and m is from scanf(), so I can not initialized n and m.  and i try your solution, the problem is not solved.

Comment: @Annndy Of course you can, simply put the array declaration _after_ the `scanf` (and after n and m has been verified to contain sane values).

Answer (score 1):

n and m have indetermined values at the point that you declare the array.

```
int n, m;

int ar[n][m]; // can be any value for n and m
```

You should read up on dynamically allocating arrays

Comment: `ar` is a VLA, not dynamically allocated. And using them **correctly** is absolutely fine.